# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS to use an IP address of 192.168.1.x

Tags: networking, server, ip

Currently, my home server is using a static local IP of 192.168.70.16. It works fine for in-house use, but I can't send WoL packets to it or forward any ports for it because it's not on the 192.168.1.x range of IPs, and therefore my router doesn't recognize it on the list of active devices. How can I change this?

This is what my current netplan looks like:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.70.16/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 192.168.70.254]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.70.254
  version: 2
```

Comment: Maybe look at the subnet mask on your router -- change 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0